# What is meant by "Memory Pressure"?

Tags: .net, windows, memory-management, garbage-collection, clr

Reading through [Tess Ferrandez' Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2008/04/17/how-does-the-gc-work-and-what-are-the-sizes-of-the-different-generations/#collections) on garbage collection, she says that there are 3 possible causes for a collection:

> 1. When you allocate a new object and the generation 0 budget is reached, i.e. if the new object would cause it to go over-budget.
> 2. When someone calls GC.Collect (Induced GC)
> 3. Based on memory pressure

I understand points 1 and 2, but what is meant by *memory pressure* in point 3?

I had assumed it was the general memory available in the system, but if the system really did use up all of its memory then I'd imagine the whole system would blue-screen.

What is actually meant by *memory pressure*?  How does it differ from exceeding a generation's budget?

Comment: Guys like Tess have access to Microsoft source code, so when they say something you don't fully understand, it is very likely that only via code reading the questions can be answered. https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/tree/master/Documentation .NET Core is now open source with some Microsoft internal materials published, so you might get the answers yourself.

Comment: Look up the differencebetween address space, physical memory and virtual memory. You won't crash (typically), since physical memory is backed / exceeded by virtual - which, however, is slow. "memory pressure", in this context, certainly refers to near-exhaustion of physical memory or address space.

Comment: There is another mechanism, haven't yet discovered how it works.  Easy to try yourself, write a loop that allocates a byte[85000] array.  They come from the large object heap, normally only collected by a gen#2 collection.  But works fine, nothing blows up.  I assume Tess is talking about GC.AddMemoryPressure().

Comment: @HansPassant I've done that experiment before, it does indeed throw an `OutOfMemoryException` after a while.

Comment: @HansPassant I thought the `GC.AddMemoryPressure` & `GC.RemoveMemoryPressure` were to record unmanaged memory that was being used so that the GC could take it into account when calculating budget usage..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In point 3, Tess refers to "low memory notification" send by Windows in case of running out of available memory. Applications may listen to that notification - to react somehow before something worse happens (for example, saving its crucial data and so on, so forth). Well-behaving applications may even try to help the OS by trimming their own memory usage.

CLR is listening for low memory notification. When it happens, GC is triggered and generally, it makes GCs more aggressive. The benefits are mutual because reducing the pressure on memory helps all applications in the system (including the .NET app itself).

When exactly low memory notification is sent is not so well documented. According to the comment in the internal [`System.Runtime.Caching.PhysicalMemoryMonitor`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Runtime.Caching/System/Caching/PhysicalMemoryMonitor.cs,bf4483db6db4cb4f,references) class, that in turn is based on comments from internal Windows implementations, the low memory notification is signaled when about 97-99% of physical memory is occupied (depending on the physical RAM amount installed in the system).